# Correlation between absolute deviation and standard deviation

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, random-variable

What is the correlation between a uniformly distributed random variable $x$ and $y \sim |N(0, x)|$?

Or what Pearson do I get for the following algorithm when $n \to \infty$?

[image]

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
n= 10000
std = np.random.uniform(low=0.0001, high=10.0, size=(n, 1))
abs_deviation = np.abs(np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=std, size=(n, 1)))
plt.plot(std, abs_deviation, ".")
print(pearsonr(std.flatten(), abs_deviation.flatten()))
plt.xlabel("std")
plt.ylabel("abs_deviation")
plt.xlabel("std")
plt.ylabel("abs_deviation")
```

PearsonRResult(statistic=0.5503903841937862, pvalue=0.0)

Comment: Can you tell us what the algorithm does?  E.g. selects a uniform value in $[0.0001,10]$ and uses that as the standard deviation of of a normal random variable with mean $0$, and then the correlation between the absolute value of the normal random variable and the standard deviation?

Comment: You may find it useful to know that a [half-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution) has mean $\sigma \sqrt{\frac2\pi}$ and variance $\sigma^2\left(1-\frac2\pi\right)$

Comment: Your description of the algorithm is correct!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have $X \sim \mathrm{Unif}(a,b)$, with $a,b>0$, and $Y|X=x \sim \mathcal{N}(0, x^2)$. Notice that we can write $Y=Z X$, where $Z$ is standard normal (and $Z \perp \!\!\! \perp X$).

The covariance we are looking for is
$$
\mathrm{Cov}(X,|Y|)=\mathrm{Cov}(X, |Z|X) = \mathbb{E}(X^2|Z|)  - \mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(|Z| X) = \mathrm{Var}(X)\mathbb{E}(|Z|)
$$
and the correlation is, thus,
$$
\mathrm{Corr}(X,|Y|)=\frac{ \mathrm{Var}(X)\mathbb{E}(|Z|)}{ \sqrt{\mathrm{Var}(X)\mathrm{Var}(|Y|)}}=\sqrt{\frac{\mathrm{Var}(X)}{\mathrm{Var}(|Y|)}}\mathbb{E}(|Z|)
$$
and we can use standard distributional results to find the answer ($|Z|$ is [chi-distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution)).

Edit: for the final bit we also need:
$$
\mathrm{Var}(|Y|)=\mathrm{Var}(X|Z|)=\mathbb{E}(X^2 Z^2)-\mathbb{E}(X|Z|)^2=
\mathbb{E}(X^2) \mathbb{E}(Z^2)-\mathbb{E}(X)^2\mathbb{E}(|Z|)^2
$$

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! I get Cov(X, |Y|) = 0.552 which seems to fit the empirical observation :)